# Android Studio App Website Login+Button Click

Tags: android, selenium, appium, jsoup, htmlunit

what can I use for Website Login + Button click on sub site for Android App in Android Studio?
For login I used JSoup and it works, but I didn't find anything to click a button.
I have to been logged in for that click.

```
What I found...
HTMLUnit < not for Android App?
Selenium < not for Android App?
Appium < I didnt get it installed very complicated..
```

Edit: Is there no other solution to do this simple thing? I didn't get it working htmlunit-android

Answer (score 1):

Have started to make HtmlUnit working on Android - see https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit-android.

There is only a SNAPSHOT build so far but a release might be available soon.
Any help e.g. testing new builds is welcome.

https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit/issues/133

Comment: Thanks and how can I implement it in Android Studio?

Comment: I guess you use maven for building your android project - if yes simply replace the HtmlUnit dependency the htmlunit-andorid one. But because there in no release so far you have to use the snapshot dependency (and add the sonatype snapshot repo). Have added some more info to the read.me. If it still not works please open a issue for the github project and we can discuss it there.

Comment: no i don't use maven, i use with gradle

Comment: but this is the same for gradle, only the syntax for defining the dependency is different

Comment: Yes, but how can I add the snapshot in gradle?

Comment: no one knows? i can't figure it out.